# VSCode xdebug pathMapping

Tags: xdebug, visual-studio-code

I try to setup xdebug in visual studio code.
I found some answers and all  are unclear to me. I am not sure if I should post a comment or ask a new question

Apparently I have to set the pathMappings property in the launch json file

I don’t know what to put in it

To access the server I use http://defserver:12345 it runs on an ibmi remote
Om my computer I have a mapping X:\phptest  where phptest is the rood of the webserver
X: is a maps to \ defserver \PHP

So what am I supposed to put into the pathMappings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prop maps the server

https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug#remote-host-debugging

```
"pathMappings": {
  "<the root dir of the app on the server>": "${workspaceFolder}/<the root dir of project on your machine, relative to workspace root>",
}
```

According to the data you put into the question:

```
"pathMappings": {
  "x:/defserver/PHP": "x:/phptest"
}
```

Comment: I am not sure f I have state the question correctly there is no mapping to x:/defserver/php there is however a mapping to //defserver/php

so the root would be / since I am debugging relative to the root an the workspacefolder is the same as the root directory

Comment: I got it. `//defserver/php` is a network dir. The network dir `//defserver/php` is mapped to dev local dir `x:/phptest`. So, in the server, where is the path to `//defserver/php` locally?

Comment: sorry for the late reaction on the ibm i this would be /php i try this out thanks

Comment: I have tryed this:

"pathMappings": {
                "/defserver/php": "X:/phptest"
              }
     
     I get the message 
     
     Unable to open 'proxy.php': File not found (file:///php/idlide/server/utils/proxy.php).

Comment: sorry is see my previous comment is incorrect is should say:
 "pathMappings": { "/php": "X:/phptest" }  got the wrong on my clibboard sorry

Comment: somehow  "pathMappings": { "///php": "${workspaceFolder}" } seems to work
I don't realy understand why /// 
is this an IBMI thing? 
anyway you're answer helped me in the end to understand what is supposed to go where  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:
this seemed to work fine:

```
"pathMappings": {
   "///php":"${workspaceFolder}"
 }
```